# No Audio Output on an Asus G74S

Tags: 11.10, sound

In 11.10 on an Asus G74S I have no audio output. I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux and want to learn how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference